# ListView not rendering properly using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It has been a while, since the last time I did some development for mobile. Now, I'm trying to refresh my knowledge using Xamarin Forms.

I created a Xamarin Froms project. However, I'm having some problems to render a collection of data into a ListView Content. I can only see the first element of tree Labels.

This is the XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ExampleBooks.View.BooksView"
             Title="Books">

  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
      <ListView x:Name="ListViewBooks"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical">
                  <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Author}" FontSize="Small"></Label>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="14"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is the screenshot of how the data using the above code is rendered:

[image: Screenshot ListView]

As you can see, the **Labels** for **Autor** and **Description** don't displayed. As far I as know, all tree elements inside the nested StackLayout in the ListView should be displayed. However, I can only see the fist one.

I have try playing around with the Padding and Spacing attributes. But, none of them seems to help.

Do I missing something here? Any help/clue would help.

P.D. I'm using an Android Emulator. However, the same is happening in a Windows Phone emulator.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't bind author and description, and just set them to static text does it work? By the way you should never put a ListView in a ScrollView, this isn't causing your problem but still a bad idea.

Comment: Also try removing VerticalOptions=Center from the first label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase your `ListView`'s `RowHeight`:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewBooks"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
          RowHeight="100">
```

[image]

Comment: @MikePR I would suggest not putting a static value for your `ListView.RowHight` since the text size and positioning could be different on different devices, orientations, and text size settings controlled by the device. It would be better to set `ListView.HasUnevenRows` to `true`.